# Display edit and delete button using content view

Tags: views

i am using blog entry content type  and i am displaying blog entry using content view .But their is no any edit and delete button how to add it while using content.Edit and delete button is working only when we use field view.Any idea how to make edit and delete button working when using content view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node Full Content is displayed using node.tpl.php. If you would like to override tpl you can copy node.tpl.php and rename it to node--blog.tpl.php in your theme templates folder. For more information refer [Drupal 7 Template Suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089656).

You can add Edit and Delete buttons using below code to the overrided template..

```
<?php 
   if (drupal_valid_path('node/' . $node->nid . '/edit')) {
     print l('Edit', 'node/' . $node->nid . '/edit'); 
   }
?>
<?php 
   if (drupal_valid_path('node/' . $node->nid . '/delete')) {
     print l('Delete', 'node/' . $node->nid . '/delete');
   }
?>
```

Comment: Everything is fine but Edit and delete button dipalying for other users also.How to hide edit and delete button for other users.

Comment: Make sure other users don't have edit / delete permissions in permissions list ...

Comment: Updated code for checking permissions..

Comment: function drupal_valid_path Checks a path exists and the current user has access to it.Thank you Anil ..this above code is working very fine as per my requirement..

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers above fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.

Comment: i require at least 15 reputation to do so..

Comment: For upvote you need 15 reputation... To accept answers you can click on Tick Mark .. For more info http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work